# Assigning user input operators to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a situation in which the user inputs a number and an operator and the output is the (user number) (user operator) on a list of 1 through 10.

This is hard to explain, but here's the code:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))

oper = input("Choose a math operation (+, -, *): ")
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(num)
```

And I get lost there. I want to get something that looks like

```
num   oper   1   =   (whatever num and the operator and 1 equal)
num   oper   2   =   (whatever num and the operator and 2 equal)
```

And so on.

So my question is: How do you assign a user-inputted operator to a variable?

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html) module to set up a dictionary of operator functions, like so:

```
import operator

operator_dict = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
}
num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))

oper = input("Choose a math operation (+, -, *): ")
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(operator_dict[oper](float(num), i))
```

An example session:

```
Enter a number greater than 1: 3
Choose a math operation (+, -, *): *
3.0
6.0
9.0
12.0
15.0
18.0
21.0
24.0
27.0
30.0
```

Answer (score 3):

From what you say here:

> I'm trying to set up a situation in which the user inputs a number and
>   an operator and the output is the (user number) (user operator) on a
>   list of 1 through 10.

I think you want to do this:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))

oper = input("Choose a math operation (+, -, *): ")
for i in range(1, 11):
    if oper == "+":
       print(num+i)
    elif oper == "-":
       print (num-i)
    elif oper == "*":
       print (num*i)
```

Comment: this is good but you could move the if block outside the loop

Comment: This is something that eval can be used for in a more efficient way.

Comment: Eval is something you generally want to avoid, even though it can help.

Comment: I prefer the if block (or a dictionary lookup) as it allows the programmer to control exactly which operations are allowed

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want something like this:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))

oper = raw_input("Choose a math operation (+, -, *): ")
for i in range(1, 11):
    if oper == '+':
        print(num, oper, i, '=', num + i)
    elif oper == '-':
        print(num, oper, i, '=', num - i)
    elif oper == '*':
        print(num, oper, i, '=', num * i)
    else:
        print('operator is not supported')
```

Output:

```
Enter a number greater than 1: 2
Choose a math operation (+, -, *): *
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
2 * 7 = 14
2 * 8 = 16
2 * 9 = 18
2 * 10 = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

[Eval can be used here:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

```
num = str(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))

oper = str(input("Choose a math operation (+, -, *, /, %, //): "))
if oper in ["+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "//"]:
    for i in range(1, 11):
        operation = num + oper + str(i) #Combine the string that is the operation
        print("{} {} {} = {}".format(num,oper,str(i),eval(operation)))
else: #if it is not in our approved items
    print("Operation not supported.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this to create a function, which within itself has all these if/elif conditions, since python does not recognize strings as operators.

The function may look a little bit like:

```
def operation(number1, number2, operator):
    if operator == '+':
        return number1 + number2
    elif operator == '-':
        return number1 - number2
```

And so on. Then you can call this function in a for loop, like this:

```
for n in range(10):
    otherNumber = n + 1
    print(yourNumber, otherNumber, operator)
```